# What could be causing my gas fireplace to shut off?

Tags: hvac

I have a gas fireplace that is 4 years old, that shuts off after a couple of minutes. The  pilot lights ok, then the burners turn on and work fine for about 3 minutes. After that the entire fireplace shuts off, even pilot.

If the glass door is kept open, then the  fireplace works fine.

What is the fix for this problem?

I sprayed wd40 to clean the entire pilot/burner assembly, but problem still persists.

Comment: Could be a problem with the flame sensor, or some type of limit switch. Do you happen to know the make and model, or have any documentation for the fireplace?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a draft issue that disturbs the pilot flame when the doors are closed. Or it could be that the flu/chimney is closed and chokes out the flame when the door is closed.

First check that the chimney is open and clear. If it is, then light the pilot only and observe the pilot flame as you close the doors. If you can see the pilot with the doors closed, then observe if the pilot flame starts "dancing" around like it is getting blown on. If so, you could try adjusting the ignition sensor closer to the flame or at least in the direction that the flame tends to go when the doors are closed.

Check if there is a fresh air intake adjustment on the unit and try different settings.

Also, there have been times when I had to actually put a ceramic or steel cover over the pilot flame/sensor to keep drafts from blowing it out when it was running.

Comment: I'll add, if it's cold out, and you just lit the pilot light, the issue might be that the chimney is too cold.  Try leaving just the pilot lit for several hours to warm up the chimney and then try lighting the fireplace.